# Editing a datagridview on a windows forms from behind a WCF layer using Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, datagridview, self-tracking-entities, batch-updates

I am using self-tracking entities from across a WCF Layer to bind a datagridview on a Windows forms application. All working fine.

My problem is that when I am editing a cell, the moment I move out (cellendedit) the row shows clean. There is this small icon that shows the row to be dirty when you are editing, and should continue to show so until you save the data.

Basically I lose my changes the dirty state the moment I move out of the cell. Now I can actually manually get the changes to be updated by creating a list of updated objects and the updating them in a loop. However, I want to know if there is a cleaner approach that allows a batch update that comes out of the box in EF.

Do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Self-Tracking-Entities track their status automatically. I just had to re-attach the updated entities and I was good. Thanks anyways.